# Accessing static file/folder from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have couple of generated pages, which I want rails to route to.

Example, in my rails root, I have a folder, 'generated' which has lot of generated web pages (static html, with their own stylesheets and images relative to their path).

I want to tell rails that allow them to routable, like how apache, nginx allows you to do it. 
This is only for development mode, btw. I know this could be done very easily using nginx/apache in production.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1.

you can put those "generated" folders in your public directory & just link to it within your views

Option 2.

Move those "generated" folders in app/views directly, add a StaticPage controller & render them. see [this example](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec%3astatic_pages)